# How to add multiple series dynamically and update its data dynamically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

my task is to add series dynamically  and keep updating their data, which is received by ajax calls.
i know series can be added dynamically by declaring highchart funciton global. and using series.addseries() function , and also data can be updated by using settimout request to ajax call and updating points by using series.addpoint() function.

i have done both the work separably. but when i combine both the technique, data is not added to highchart. i have done lot of research on this, and i am not finding reason for not adding the data. infact script hang the browser. 
i have checked the series object, which show x-data and y-data are processed. only difference i find is isDirty field and isDirtydata field are set to true. dont know the reason.
here is the full code

```
var serverUrl = 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':8000'
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
data={}
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function () {
        console.log("highcharts")
         $('#first').highcharts({
              chart: {
                  type: 'spline',
                  //marginRight: 150,
                  marginBottom: 5,
                  events: {
                      load: requestData(data)
                          }
              },
              title: {
                  text: 'Server Monitroting Tool'
              },
              subtitle: {
                  text:  'Cpu usage, Memory Usage,Disk Usage,Mongo Usage'
              },
              xAxis: {
              type: 'datetime',
              categories: ['TIME'],
                    dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                    hour: '%I %p',
                    minute: '%I:%M %p'
                }
              },
              yAxis:{
                  showEmpty:false
              },

                  legend:
                  {
                    backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5',
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    floating: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                    x: 60,
                    y: 9,
                    shadow: false,
                    border: 0,
                    borderRadius: 0,
                    borderWidth: 0
              },
              series: {}
          });
          });
     from_date=new Date().getTime()-60000;

    function requestData(data)
    {
        if(!data)
        {
            console.log("default ")
        }
        else
        {
        console.log("requesting")
        $.ajax({
            url:serverUrl+'/api/fetch_params/',
            type:'GET',
            data:data,
            success:function(response)
            {
             console.log("in success")
            //data = {'type':TypeOfParameter,'hostname':hostname,'sub-type':sub_type,'param':sub_type_parameter,'from-date':from_date}
            var id=data['sub-type']+data['param']
            var series = chart.get(id)
            shift = series.data.length > 100; // shift if the series is longer than 300 (drop oldest point)

            response= $.parseJSON(response)
            var x=data['sub-type']
            all_data=response.response.data[x]

    //                console.log(new Date(from_date),'latest timestamp')
                console.log(series)
            console.log("data",all_data)

            from_date=all_data[all_data.length-1][0]
//            console.log(from_date)
//                series.isDirty=false
//                series.isDirtyData=false
            for (var i = 0; i < all_data.length; i++)
            {
                series.addPoint({ x: all_data[i][0],y: all_data[i][1],id: i},false,shift);
            }
            console.log("series object",series)
    //                    chart.redraw();
                console.log(" parameter",data)
                data['from-date']=from_date

            console.log("data",series.data)
    //                console.log(chart)
            setTimeout(requestData(data), 10000);
            console.log("out of success")
            },

            cache:false,
            error:function()
            {
                console.log("err")

            }
        });
        }

    }

    $.ajax({
        url:serverUrl+'/api/fetch_all_servers/',
        type:'GET',
        success:function(response){
            response = $.parseJSON(response)
            sd = response.response.all_servers
            $('input[name=select_menue]').optionTree(sd)
        },
        error:function(){
            console.log('error')
        }
    });

    $('.param-button').live('click',function(e){
        e.stopPropagation()
    })

    $('param-select').live('hover',function(){
       $(this).find('.type-select').show()
    });

    $('.final_value').live('change',function(){
        select_name = 'select_menue_'
        param_list = []
        var param=$('select[name="'+select_name+'"] option:selected').attr('value')
        while(param){
            param_list.push(param)
            select_name += '_'
            var param=$('select[name="'+select_name+'"] option:selected').attr('value')
        }
        console.log(param_list,"param_list")
        from_date=new Date().getTime()-300000  //5 minute data
        hostname=param_list[0]
        TypeOfParameter= param_list[1]
        sub_type_parameter=param_list[param_list.length-1]
        data = {'type':TypeOfParameter,'hostname':hostname,'param':sub_type_parameter,'from-date':from_date}
        var sub_type;
        if(param_list.length==4){
            sub_type=param_list[2]
            data['sub-type'] = sub_type
        }
        else
        {
            sub_type=sub_type_parameter
        }
//        console.log(hostname,TypeOfParameter,sub_type,sub_type_parameter)

       data = {'type':TypeOfParameter,'hostname':hostname,'sub-type':sub_type,'param':sub_type_parameter,'from-date':from_date}
       requestData(data)

        $('#loadingmessage').show();  // show the loading message.


        chart = $('#first').highcharts();

        if(TypeOfParameter=='cpu')
        {
            console.log("adding axis")
             chart.addAxis({ // Primary yAxis


                          id:'Cpu_axis'+sub_type_parameter,
                          labels: {
                              formatter: function() {
                                  return this.value;
                              },
                              style: {
                                  color: '#89A54E'
                                  }
                          },
                          title: {
                              text: "core "+ sub_type+ " "+sub_type_parameter,
                              style: {
                                  color: '#89A54E'
                              }
                          },

            lineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: '#08F'

                      });



         console.log("adding series")
        chart.addSeries({
            id:sub_type+sub_type_parameter,
            name: "core "+sub_type+" "+sub_type_parameter,
            data :[],

            tooltip : {
                valueSuffix: ' %'
                    },
                 yAxis:'Cpu_axis'+sub_type_parameter
                })
            console.log("series out")


        }
        if(TypeOfParameter=='memory')
        {
            chart.addAxis    ({
            id:'memory'+sub_type_parameter,
            labels:{
                     formatter: function() {
                                  return this.value +'%';
                              },
                      style: {
                          color: '#89C54F'
                          }
                    },

            title: {
                text:sub_type+" "+sub_type_parameter
            },
            lineWidth: .5,
            lineColor: '#08F',
            opposite: true
        });
        chart.addSeries({
            id:sub_type+sub_type_parameter,
            name: sub_type+'memory usage',
            data: [],
            tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
                },
          yAxis:'memory'+sub_type_parameter
        });
        }

     if(TypeOfParameter=='disk')
        {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'second',
                defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                events: {
                    load: requestData
                }
            },
            title: {

                text: 'disk Usage'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150,
                maxZoom: 20 * 1000
            },
            yAxis: {
                minPadding: 0.2,
                maxPadding: 0.2,
                title: {
                    text: 'disk',
                    margin: 80
                }
            },
            series: [{
                id:sub_type+sub_type_parameter,
                name: 'disk',
                data: []
            }]
});
        }
     if(TypeOfParameter=='db')
        {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'second',
                defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                events: {
                    load: requestData
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'mongo Usage'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150,
                maxZoom: 20 * 1000
            },
            yAxis: {
                minPadding: 0.2,
                maxPadding: 0.2,
                title: {
                    text: 'mmongo',
                    margin: 80
                }
            },
            series: [{
                id:sub_type+sub_type_parameter,
                name: 'mongo',
                data: []
            }]
});
        }
     if(TypeOfParameter=='redis')
        {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'second',
                defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                events: {
                    load: requestData
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'redis Usage'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150,
                maxZoom: 20 * 1000
            },
            yAxis: {
                minPadding: 0.2,
                maxPadding: 0.2,
                title: {
                    text: 'redis',
                    margin: 80
                }
            },
            series: [{
                id:sub_type+sub_type_parameter,
                name: 'redis',
                data: []
            }]
    });
                    }
                $('#loadingmessage').hide(); // hide the loading message




        }
            )
            });
```

i am stuck on this problem for quite a while. and still not able to figure out the solution.
here is the full code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/shivnarayans/L8nxN/)
someone please please help. feeling frustrated ..:-(

Comment: This: `series: {}` should be: `series: []`. Also, I see you have two charts, assigned to one variable..? Both charts use the same requestData() function? I advice to start with one chart, ane make it work, then start to work with two charts..

Comment: hey @PawełFus keeping series:{} worked for me to add multiple series dyncamilly. also requestData is working with one series for me.
now i have declared highchart object globally so as to add all series into one highchart . let me know what wrong i am doing ?

Comment: For me declaration for series is wrong.. I'm sorry but witout seeing and debugging this 'live' I won't be able to help you.

Comment: Please create a small reproducible example of the problem you are having.  Very few people are going to be willing to wade through the amount of code above to find issues.

Answer (score 0):

As you know the addPoint method is bit dangerous when dealing with quite lots points. It is recommended to disable redraw per point when dealing with many new points - more info http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint() , I notice you are doing that already in the loop statement, but why did you commented out? have you tried enabling again. Make sure chart.redraw works by adding a new redraw chart event, and set an alert or console log.

Also you may try using, below as part of ajax, instead of cache:false. I had some problems in past.
headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'   }

Cheers